# Trouble bringing a cloned cluster shared volume disk online

Tags: hyper-v, storage-area-network, cluster-shared-volumes

I have a Hyper-V cluster (2008 R2) with a CSV that I want to clone. The CSV is on a fibre channel SAN (HP MSA M3 P2000 G3). I cloned a volume from the SAN side of things, and have mapped it to my cluster nodes. The cluster nodes can see the volume, but they are marked as offline, reserved.

As far as I can tell, I am having the same problem as outlined in this question:
[Changing 'disk ID' of Windows GPT disk via Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/660605/changing-disk-id-of-windows-gpt-disk-via-linux) except that I'm working with fibre channel.

When I run `diskpart` and get the `uniqueid disk`, both the original disk and cloned disk share the same ID. I think this is the problem.

```
DISKPART> select disk 10
Disk 10 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> uniqueid disk
Disk ID: 65DC665F
DISKPART> select disk 4
Disk 4 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> uniqueid disk
Disk ID: 65DC665F
```

Additionally, when I check the attributes on the clone, it shows as clustered:

```
DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : Yes
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : Yes
```

I've also checked on the SAN, and there are no reservations on the cloned volume.

The solutions I've running across so far:

- Online the disk from the cluster owner of the original volume, at which point the conflicting unique ID should be resolved. This is not working for me, I am unable to online the disk from the CSV's current owner.
- Map the volume to a non-clustered server, which should be able to mount the volume, and then modify the uniqueid. Which I can't do, only cluster nodes are plugged into the FC switch.
- Offline the original CSV, bring the clone online. An option I'd like to avoid, the CSV contains a production server's VHD.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just create a new volume rather than cloning the existing volume?

Comment: I want to test the VM on some other hosts, so I need access to the VHD.

Comment: OK,  I'm not really understanding why you need to clone the CSV in order to access the VHD. Is the destination host connected to the same CSV as the source host? If not, why not just create a new CSV for the destination host, export the VM from the source host, import it on the destination host and go from there?

Comment: @joeqwerty I've explored that route, I might be missing something, but I have not found a way to export while the VM is running.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I missed the point that you're running 2008 R2. Live VM exports aren't possible for you. You'd have to shut down the VM to export it. An alternative would be to backup the VM (live) and restore it to the destination host. There are a number of Hyper-V backup products on the market that will do this. One that I often use is Trilead. Their free version can perform a live backup of the VM. It's a handy tool to have around whether or not you use it for this particular task. - https://www.trilead.com/editions/

Comment: No worries. One of the reasons I was trying to go with the SAN side clone was that I think there is a problem with the MPIO on one+ of the cluster nodes. I shutdown the VM a few days ago during business hours after it became unresponsive, just before that it was showing it was waiting on disk io 99% of the time. It has a 50g VHD, which was reporting that it would take over 23 hours to copy. I ended up moving it around between cluster nodes and booting it back up without getting a good copy of the VHD. I'm thinking my only option is to down it off hours and hope a copy completes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this guide: http://support.altaro.com/customer/portal/articles/1115503-how-can-i-change-the-disk-id-of-a-drive-

> **To view the Disk ID:**
>
> - Open Command prompt
> - Enter the command `DISKPART` and hit enter
> - Enter the command  `LIST DISK`  and hit enter to list all available disks
> - Enter `SELECT DISK X` (Substitute  "X" for the number of the disk you wish to select) and hit enter
> - Enter `UNIQUEID DISK`  and hit enter
> - A four byte disk ID will be returned, for example: "e9eb3aa5"
>
> **To Change the Disk ID:**
>
> - Open Command prompt
> - Enter the command `DISKPART` and hit enter
> - Enter the command `LIST DISK`  and hit enter to list all available disks
> - Enter `SELECT DISK X` (Substitute  "X" for the number of the disk you wish to select)
> - Enter `UNIQUEID DISK ID=a4e19dc0` and hit enter
> - This will change the Disk ID to "a4e19dc0"
> - Enter `UNIQUEID DISK` and hit enter to view the new Disk ID

Comment: DiskPart has encountered an error: The media is write protected.
See the System Event Log for more information.
The disk is offline and read only